# Regression when the response is a proportion that can be 0 or 1

Tags: r, multiple-regression, nonlinear-regression

I have two datasets a training and a test dataset. The dependent variable is a proportion and there are 54 predictors which are positive and negative real numbers and another 7 predictors that are text.

There are three response variables. Total the normalized total number of hits. Treatment the normalized total number during treatment and a percent which is a ratio of the other two responses.

At the moment using lm on the percent prediction data I have a corolation of .4. 85% of the varibles are within 20% of their target. For the treatment response variable using glm in poisson mode i have a correlation of .6 percent but the variables do not match the target data at all.

I have two main issues I need advice on:

(1) it rejected the text predictors because it said factor has new level(s)
I would like it to ignore the information for those that have new level but not disregard it for those that have the correct information how do i do that?

(2) To make my dependent variable a real number, rather than a proportion bounded between 0 and 1, I was advised to transform the response using, for example, the logit transform or the Normal quantile function (`qnorm` in R). The problem is that these transformations (and others like it) will map 0 and 1 to non-finite values. How can I model these data in a regression setting when the response is a proportion that can be 0 or 1?

Using linear regression with outlier removal I am able to get 2239 of 2583 testing data within 20% of their actual value I would like to have that many within 10%.

Using the posson distribution glm the amount of treatment correlates with 69%.

Ignoring this second issue for the moment, I transform the y~x1+x2 such that y=log(y/(1-y)) the correlation of my predictions to actual data drops from 6% to 2%
This is what the data looks like after the logit transform

[image: log distribution]

This is what the data looks like before the log distribution
[image: normal percentages]

Comment: Do you mean to say that you have 61 numeric characteristics and 7 character valued charactersistics? What is your outcome in this study? If you put text values into a regression model, I think the default is to cast them into factors, meaning that you will adjust for indicators for each level of the text field. I can't say anything about whether a probit/logic model makes sense unless you describe what the variables are, what the outcome is, and what you're interested in measuring.

Comment: @AdamO I have 54 numeric characteristics and 7 text characteristics. the outcome of the study is a prediction of a treatment the variables are RNA sequencing information and intrinsic numeric variables is that enough information?

Comment: What is the purpose of the code you've pasted there? From what I can tell it doesn't add anything to the question. If it needs to be there, what is `mod` in the initial line? Is some code missing?

Comment: I don't understand the second comment. It seems to suggest that the values 0 and 1 can occur. I think what Macro suggested transformations and I concurred we were both thinking of a continuous random variable on the interval [0,1] and not a random variable with discrete components at 0 and 1. The Q - Q plots definitely show that the transformations did not make the residuals normal.  I don't understand the other curves at all.

Comment: @MichaelChernick yes the values 0 and 1 can occur but in the log transformation i removed or added .001 from them to keep them for occurring.

Comment: I understand how you can choose the transformation so as not to divide by zero. That isn't the problem I am worrying about. The idea of the transformation was to take a continuous variable on a a bounded domain and map it to a continuous variable over an unbounded range. Your variable has discrete components and thats a problem that the transformation doesn't fix. I think we need to understand your problem better. Linear regression may not be the technique to apply to your problem.

Comment: what kind of additional information do you think would help? what other technique would work better?

Comment: I guess I don't understand your data.  What do these proportions represent?  Besides be restricted to be between 0 and 1 what other characteristics do they have.  You neglected to tell us that 0 and 1 occur with probability > 0.  Are there other proportions that can occur with probability > 0? The behavior of these proportions determine if modeling assumptions are violated so badly that the modle for the data is inappropriate.  What method would be appropriate depends on the information we don't yet have.

Comment: I am thinking of categorical data analysis as a possibility or Poisson regression if the proportions are really counts that are converted to proportions.  But these are stabs in the dark do to my current level of ignorance of your problem.

Comment: these proportions represents the viability of a treatment. a 1 means the treatment was completely ineffective and a 0 means the treatment may have been 100% effective. the higher the proportion the more interesting the individual is to my study. lm does a pretty good job at estimating the percentage 75% but i need to find a way to include the text data because they have the highest R^2 data and do the best job categorizing the data. lm does a bad job at estimating the individual counts which form the ratio of treatment/total. i'll google poisson regression :)

Comment: @MichaelChernick, Based on the residual/fitted plot, it looks like the proportions vary pretty continuously between 0 and 1, but a large proportion of the data is either 0 or 1 - from my chat conversation with casey, I found out that around 1000 of the ~2800 cases were 0s and another 500 or so were 1s (these are very approximate). At that point, I was a little unsure what to recommend, so I suggested he modify the question to hear what others have to say. My very ad-hoc recommendation was to add a small number to 0 (and subtract a small number from 1) so that they are mapped to finite values.

Comment: Poisson (or some other discrete) regression is not a bad idea - then the dependent variable would be the count, not the proportion. If the denominator ('total', apparently) is different for each response, then you will want to include an offset in the model.

Comment: it may just be that that part of the experiment is indeterminant which is ok its a result all the same

Comment: @caseyr547 Did you see my second answer suggesting negative binomial regression? It would be interesting to see what happens if you try that.  Can you tell if your data are overdispersed?

Comment: @MichaelChernick i'll look at your second answer when i get a chance my resuslts of correlation of 69% were inacuarte because of a subset error.

Comment: Someone didn't like my second answer and gave me a downvote.  I debated adding as a comment because it was asking for a clarification to help give better answers to the original question.  But it also answered the OPs second question.

Comment: @casey547 Did you estimate the mean and variance of the count distribution?  If they are close to equal the Poisson model may be the best.  If the variance is much larger than the mean then an overdispersed count model like the negative binomial might be better. Keep in mind the data is what it is.  The Poisson model might be the best you can do.

Comment: @MichaelChernick the mean of the percent response is .09 and the variance is .015 the mean of the treatment is 120.35 and the variance is 1137005.039. i don't understand how to do a count distribution if you explain more about it i will do it too.

Comment: @caset547 the response variable is the Poisson so compare the mean value of the response (not percent response) and compare it to the variance of the response.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3493/discussion-between-caseyr547-and-michael-chernick)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if Poisson regression seemed to help it may be because the right thing to do is to treat the outcomes as counts.  But if it is not satisfactory negative binomial regression might be better.  It allows for overdispersion and is a lot more flexible.  The Poisson distribution have the property that the mean equals the variance.  In real examples the variance can be less than the mean (underdispersed) or greater (overdispersed).  Negative binomial regression gets around that problem because the varaince doen't have to equal teh mean.  Joe Hilbe has a nice book dedicated to negative binomial regression for count data models. Maybe you can do that with your software.

Comment: Can you say why the negative binomial is preferable to an overdispersed Poisson? Particularly since the negative binomial distribution arises as the number of failures before the $k$'th success in a sequence of bernoulli trials, which doesn't really make sense as a data generating mechanism in this case

Comment: ok as best i can tell the poison worked very well and correlates to 63% to treatment after i made a correction but the means squared error =1/(N*POWER(SUM(actual-prediction),2)) is still very low the numbers correlate but they are not accurate. what do i do to make them accurate? should i start a new question? i still need help with the first part of this question i would rather not have to number all the categories but i can if that is the only way.

Comment: The Negative binomial causes a 13% drop in correlation from the poisson to 50% the numbers are also less accurate dropping the squar means from e-21 to e-150

Comment: Why don't you want the mean square error to be low?  It measures the goodness of fit .  It should be low. Your question makes it sound like you think that statistics can find a way to make something as accurate as you want by do some trick.  Statistics can only explain what the data tells us.  There should always be some residual variability for any model.

Comment: @MichaelChernick haha please forgive me i'm use to using artificial intelligences like svms and clusters that have more defined metrics of correctness. I think I'm going to explain this in terms of true and false positives, negatives and so I want the data to be as optimized as possible. do you think a non linear approach would provide any more optimization?

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3494/room-for-macro-and-caseyr547

Comment: @MichaelChernick, My understanding is that the overdispersed poisson gives you a variance that is linearly related to the mean. The negative binomial gives you a variance that is quadratically related to the mean. So, they are just two different models of overdispersion. Which is better probably depends on the context. But, I was thinking more basically about how the negative binomial distribution arises from a situation that does not seem plausible here. That usually seems like a good reason not to use a particular statistical model, regardless of whether it "fits" well.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [beta regression](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v34/i02/paper).  It would be helpful to know what the response variable actually represents, but I would start with logistic regression (O.K. if the proportion represents the average of a large number of Bernoulli trials) and then try beta regression (which is a much more flexible solution, where the residuals are assumed to be from a beta distribution with parameters specified by the regression).

Update: It seems that the data generating process for this problem means that it is not a straightforward regression problem, but instead it has three seperate modes of generating the response, one where it is zero, one where it is one and one where it can be any value in the range (0,1).  The way to approach such problems is by using a compond likelihood.  I have used this kind of approach for modelling rainfall, where there are lots of exact zeros for days where it doesn't rain at all.  The solution is to have a model with three outputs, one which gives the probability that it will rain, and the other two giving the shape and scale parameters of a gamma distribution which represents the amount of rain that you would see if it did rain.  The original paper on this was by Peter Williams, but I can't find it on line, so [here](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/publications/pdf/esann2003c.pdf) is my paper, which should give you the basic idea.

For this problem, you could try having a model with three outputs, one is the probability that the response is an exact zero, one that is the probability that it is an exact one and one that is a prediction of the response if it isn't an exact zero or an exact one.  I doub't you will be able to get some off-the shelf code for this, but it is the approach I would take.

Comment: The beta distribution takes on the values 0 and 1 with probability 0, and this data set comes from a distribution with a large point mass at both of these points, so beta regression probably isn't appropriate.

Comment: That is not correct.  For example the pdf of a beta distribution with alpha = beta = 1 (i.e. a uniform distribution) has the value 1 at both 0 and 1.  The beta distribution has a variety of shapes, which makes it very flexible for modelling proportions, and is fine with 0s and 1s.

Comment: The beta distribution is continuous, therefore if $X$ has a beta distribution, $P(X=0)=P(X=1)=0$. This is incompatible with there being large point masses at both 0 and 1. No values in the parameter space (positive reals) for $\alpha,\beta$ can lead to a distribution with point masses at 0 or 1. It is true that, as the parameter values approach their boundary values ($0$ and $\infty$), discreteness follows in certain examples, e.g. as $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ and $\beta \rightarrow 0$, the beta distribution converges to a Bernoulli$(p)$ distribution,where $p$ depends on the rates each goes to 0.

Comment: @Macro I was going to say that downvoting Dikran might have been unfair assuming you did it. I was thinking that it was a reasonable suggestion prior to knowing that the data has discrete components at 0 and 1 and he may have given the answer prior to that clarification.  But his defense which confuses a continuous density with a probaility mass function shows that the downvote is deserved.  I don't mean to offend but that is a serious mistake.

Comment: @Macro I am not an expert on count regression models.  I have read through Hilbe's book and have had discussions with him.  What I can say is that when the response variable is overdispersed the Poisson model may not be very good and an negative binomial can do better because it can produce the right amount of overdispersion.  The negative binomial can be derived as the point process that corresponds to the time to first failure for say a medical device.  But can also simply look at it as a count model that can fit data that may have arisen in a different way.

Comment: Maybe reading Hilbe's book would help you.

Comment: O.K. Macro, I see what you mean, and will revise my answer. However, bte regression can handle zeros and ones, however if the process also has point masses, then that is another matter entirely.

Answer (score 0):

@Dirkan Beta regression requires logit transformation. The logit transforms of 0 and 1 are -Inf and Inf. This is why beta regression cannot handle 0s and 1s.